# Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was trying to make sure code I have written in Rails only runs on the development environment. So I tried to starts the rails server with a production environment via command:

```
rails s -e production
```

I started to see the error:

```
Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.
    /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `execute'
    /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `parse'
    /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:41:in `receive_data'
    /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
    /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
    /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
    /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
    /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
    /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    script/rails:6:in `require'
    script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

So I killed the server and ran `rails s`. However, I continue to get this error no matter what I try. What can i do?

Comment: Which port are you running your server on? is it `5000`?

Comment: which operating system are you on?